# Surface Pro 2: differences between Type Cover or Type Cover 2?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, tablet, microsoft-surface

With the release of the Surface Pro 2, there is a new version of the Type Cover coming out - the Type Cover 2.

It is supposed to be an improvement over the original Type Cover, being both backlit and thinner. However, this means that the keys will have 1mm less travel, making it harder to type on. I've tried the original Type Cover and it was pretty good; I don't know if it still would be if the keys moved 1mm less.

Does anyone who is familiar with Surface hardware know

- if the original type cover is compatible with the Surface Pro 2?
- if there are any other advantages to using the new Type Cover other than the backlight and being thinner?

Comment: FYI, I love the less key travel, because I don't want to press hard! The keys should move practically without a touch at all, imho, so I love the reduced, thus improved key travel distance. Using fat key travel keyboards seriously hurts my hands. Ty for helping me find this spec via google! I also found it here, too; First look: Microsoft Surface 2 with Type Cover 2 ; ; http://appleinsider.com/articles/13/10/23/first-look-microsoft-surface-2-with-type-cover-2

Answer (score 2):

After having used both the Type Cover and Type Cover 2, I can definitively say that the reduced key travel on the Type Cover 2 is noticeable, stopping your fingers in mid-stride, and tends to be distracting for those that are used to normal height scissor switch keyboards.

The key travel on the Type Cover is **2.5mm**, while only **1.5mm** on the Type Cover 2. That's a 40% reduction.

In my opinion, the increased typing speed on the Type Cover (1) is preferable to the backlight available on the Type Cover 2.